# Template Modal Conflict

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, css, bootstrap, modal

- Joomla 3.6.5
- Joomshaper Helix 3 Template [link](http://demo.joomshaper.com/?template=helix3)
- FavimageHover Module [link](https://www.favthemes.com/joomla-extensions/product/favimagehover-responsive-joomla-module)

I have the FavimageHover module installed on my site, it works great until I try and add images via the front-end. There seems to be some sort of conflict when I edit the module causing a transparent full page modal to appear on screen. No matter where I click on screen a 'browse for image' popup appears.

It also seems like the 'select image' fields aren't displaying correctly.

I'm not sure if this is a CSS or JS issue, or even where to start troubleshooting it! When I click the tab and inspect the page I can see the following code appear in the console;

```
<a class="modal btn" title="Select" href="/dod-dev/&#10;index.php?option=com_jce&amp;view=editor&amp;plugin=browser&amp;standalone=1&amp;aebdb3fbff9f8582404c47be1b302cad=1&amp;context=23&amp;filter=images&amp;fieldid=jform_params_upload_image6&amp;folder=" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 800, y: 500}}">Select</a>
```

I don't see any errors in the console.

When I edit this module via the back end all is well. I am using the standard Joomla module manager. I should not that i've tried the default Protostar template and it works perfectly.

I have included a few images, hopefully someone can help? I'm lost :/

**Only happens when I click this tab**
[image: only heppens when I click this tab]
**These fields don't look to be displaying correctly and you can see the 'select' text appear on the top of the page**
[image: these fields don't look to be displaying correctly and you can see the 'select' text appear on the top of the page]
**This appears when I click anywhere on screen**
[image: this appears when I click anywhere on screen]

Answer (score 2):

Well the only solution / workaround I have found so far is to assign a different template when editing modules via the front end.

Thanks to Regular Labs [Advanced Template Manager](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/advancedtemplatemanager) I was able to use the default Joomla Protostar template for front end module editing **only**.

This is achieved by assigning the template as default whenever a particular URL is visited (i.e /com_config&controller). This option is available in the 'assignments' section of the AMM component.

This seems to be working so far, unless someone can see a reason as to why it wouldn't?

I have given up on trying to troubleshoot the JS / CSS issue - this is much easier.

Comment: On JSE Github repository you can find Editor Template plugin https://github.com/Joomla-StackExchange/editorTemplate which forces article editing page to use a specific template.

Comment: That looks perfect @Mikan thanks! I've never seen this before. Hopefully it's not just limited to the article editor page, and will work with the module editor page too.

Comment: You're welcome mate. If I remeber correctly, it was based on JSE Q http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/18441/different-templates-for-viewing-and-editing-articles , and made by @webchun . I haven't tested it by myself, but it certainly looks promising for that specific case scenario.